# How do I replaced the functionality of session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, safari

We have a production issue in one of our APIs such that Safari users don't
have cookies enabled by default, we redirect users, and when they come back we load
the state they had before the redirect from the session.

This doesn't work for Safari users. We have a load balancer with three servers (with sticky session on) behind it, so i can't store it in local memory instead.

I cannot store the state in a database that all servers can see because we deal with credit card data, and to be PCI complaint we can only store card data (cvn mainly) in volatile memory.

What alternatives can I use?

Comment: I think if you encrypt credit card you can keep it in database and be PCI compliance. Is it not the case?

Comment: @kaptan Yes card numbers, but not CVN. You can never store cvn in anything other than ram. In this case, we need to keep the cvn for one redirect (after we send them to their bank, they comeback to us).

Comment: This might not be really secure, but can you use web storage? http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Comment: @Keith _This specification defines an API for **persistent** data storage of key-value pair data in Web clients._ No, I can't.